# Where can i find the javaFx namespace?

Tags: java, javafx, namespaces

Scene Builder inserts several namespaces in an FXML file by default?

```
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
```

When I try to access either of these through IDEA, it tells me that there is "No XML at the location."

Oracle seems to have moved or removed them. Where can i find these (or other versions)?

Comment: Try https.  It loads in my browser with https but not http.

Comment: @BakonJarser It does not load in mine. First I get a warning about the certificate. If I bypass the warning, I get redirected to Oracle's Java page.

Comment: I don't think they ever existed (or maybe just one for the fxml namespace did). The validity of fxmls depends on the structure of java types created from the fxml and it would be impossible to keep an schema file up to date (even ignoring the fact that you can use custom classes). Both urls simply serve as identifier and the one used for javafx contains additional version info that `FXMLLoader` may use print a warning.

Comment: @fabian  This is the answer, but I can't acknowledge it as such since you wrote it as a comment.